# How to evaluate the flags field of mtd_info_user?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

The MTD driver placed inside the Linux kernel source has a [definition](https://code.woboq.org/linux/linux/include/uapi/mtd/mtd-abi.h.html#127) as below.

```
struct mtd_info_user {
    __u8 type;
    __u32 flags;
    __u32 size; /* Total size of the MTD */
    __u32 erasesize;
    __u32 writesize;
    __u32 oobsize;  /* Amount of OOB data per block (e.g. 16) */
    __u64 padding;  /* Old obsolete field; do not use */
};
```

I'm trying to understand what the `flags` field stands for. My ultimate purpose is to find a way to check if the external MTD device is healthy. I thought that the flags field can represent the actual status of the device.

Inside the `mtdchar_open(..)` function from [mtdchar.c](https://code.woboq.org/linux/linux/drivers/mtd/mtdchar.c.html#89) source code, there is a comparison as below.

```
/* You can't open it RW if it's not a writeable device */
if ((file->f_mode & FMODE_WRITE) && !(mtd->flags & MTD_WRITEABLE)) {
    ret = -EACCES;
    goto out1;
}
```

So, I guess the flags field can be evaluated by using the macros from the **mtd-abi.h** [header](https://code.woboq.org/linux/linux/include/uapi/mtd/mtd-abi.h.html).

```
#define MTD_ABSENT      0
#define MTD_RAM         1
#define MTD_ROM         2
#define MTD_NORFLASH        3
#define MTD_NANDFLASH       4   /* SLC NAND */
#define MTD_DATAFLASH       6
#define MTD_UBIVOLUME       7
#define MTD_MLCNANDFLASH    8   /* MLC NAND (including TLC) */

#define MTD_WRITEABLE       0x400   /* Device is writeable */
#define MTD_BIT_WRITEABLE   0x800   /* Single bits can be flipped */
#define MTD_NO_ERASE        0x1000  /* No erase necessary */
#define MTD_POWERUP_LOCK    0x2000  /* Always locked after reset */
```

The problem is about why some of those definitions are declared like normal integers, *e.g. MTD_ABSENT*.